# Will killing ps -f stop piped grep from executing?

Tags: 14.04, bash

If I have a command `ps -f | grep proc`, and the `ps -f` command is killed, will the `grep proc` part still reside. Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Pretend you are the `grep` command, reading `STDIN`, looking for the pattern. What happens when `ps` goes away?

Comment: Also, why is this flagged with 14.04? That's EOL and won't be getting updates for things like vulnerabilities. It'd also be off-topic for this site.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: @guiverc This post has nothing to do with 14.04 apart from the tag, so why are you posting a canned response? This question has use cases on pretty much every version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt It is very easy to switch to a different tag, and Canonical have deemed fit to provide updates for 5 years (before switching to ESM which has support elsewhere) and I don't see it as good/useful to encourage the use of unsupported/unpatched software. I'm also in the 'News' team so letting people know when a release is EOL/ESM I see as within the duties of one of my 'hats' also.

Comment: @guiverc That is cool and all, but nobody is encouraging anything here to do with use of unsupported or unpatched software. If someone asks a question, we are to answer it: correct? We aren't encouraging usage by simply fixing a problem. It is cool you are part of the news team, but the whole response of "your software is outdated and instead of me helping to answer a universal problem, ill recommend something totally irrelevant" is.. well, irrelevant.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt The date of the answers reveal it was beyond the 5 year *standard support* cycle of the 14.04 product, so readers will get an *implied* consent with using EOL software. Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, but users are on their own (this is an official Ubuntu site don't forget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't,these are multiple processes but piped within the master "proc".
So it can be simply understood as if master process is stopped so all its subtasks will be killed, stopping the complete pipeline.